# I need to erase a certain session variable from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need to erase a certain session variable from a javascript function how can i do this?

Comment: Can you give more details and maybe a code sample?

Comment: Wow. There really should be a [php-and-js-again] tag

Comment: $_session['cont_no']="smth";

i need to empty this session variable from a javascript function 
like
"<script>
function remove()
{ remove the session value }
</script>"
can this be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Sessions live on the server (not strictly true I know, but for the purposes of this answer, it's true enough).

I would write a script (PHP or somesuch) that unsets the session variable and fire off an ajax call to it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use an Ajax call to the server to access/delete the session variable as sessions are controlled/handled only on the server side, not the client side.